# первая запись для каждого id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Такая таблица:

id | timestamp| field1 | field2 | ...

```
3  1574979072  qwer  ...
2  1574977664  asdf  ...
1  1574967168  zxcv  ...
2  1574950784  wert  ...
1  1574948480  xcvv  ...
```

Необходимо получить первую запись для каждого id через поле timestamp:

```
3  1574979072  qwer  ...
2  1574950784  wert  ...
1  1574948480  xcvv  ...
```

Это работает:

```
select 
  chat_id, 
  min(timestamp) as ts 
from 
  msgall 
GROUP BY 
  chat_id 
ORDER BY ts DESC
```

Но как мне вывести остальные поля для этой первой записи (field1 | field2 | ...)? Если я их добавляю в select - начинает ругаться группировка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM msgall t1
JOIN ( SELECT chat_id, 
              MIN(timestamp) AS ts 
       FROM msgall 
       GROUP BY chat_id ) AS t2 ON t1.chat_id = t2.chat_id
                               AND t1.timestamp = t2.ts
ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC
```

Предполагается, что `(chat_id, timestamp)` - уникально.

Comment: Благодарю, конструкция работает. Но действительно возникли проблемы с уникальностью, видимо из-за проблем с подключениями, приложение иногда обрабатывало сразу несколько реквестов, которые ждали в очереди, и записывало их с одинаковым timestamp в базу. Заменил SELECT t1.* на SELECT DISTINCT и только необходимые ячейки, так как в действительности они не все были нужны. Можно считать, что задача решена!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from msgall
where (chat_id, timestamp)
in(
select 
  chat_id, 
  min(timestamp) as ts 
from 
  msgall 
GROUP BY 
  chat_id 
)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```